# Notepad++ Function List plugin: Javascript parsing rules to support nested functions

Tags: javascript, notepad++

[Using Notepad++ 5.5.1 and Function List plugin v2.0beta]

I'm trying to add to or modify the existing rules for Javascript functions in order to show nested (or member) functions in the function list.  For example:

```
function parentA (base){
  function childA (exp){
    return Math.pow(base, exp);
  }

  alert(childA(2)); // call private function
}

parentA(4); // alerts 4^2 = 16


var parentB = function(str1){
  return {
    childB: function(str2){
      alert(str1 + str2);
    }
  };
}('foo');

parentB.childB('bar'); // alerts 'foobar'
```

The **parentA** and **parentB** functions are listed, but the **childA** and **childB** functions are **not** listed.  This nested-child paradigm is common within Javascript libraries and reusable code, and important to be fully navigable in the function list.

Can this be done with groups and/or subgroups?  I've tried digging through the parsing rules for other class-based languages (that list member functions using subgroups), but I can't seem to get this to work for Javascript.

Any suggestions?  Has anyone accomplished this for their own use?  I'm probably being stupid, but I'm going crazy trying to figure this one out - please help!  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "body begin" and "body end" characters and it will work:

```
<Group name="Functions" subgroup="" icon="" child="" autoexp="0" matchcase="0" fendtobbeg="" bbegtobend="" keywords="">
     <Rules regexbeg="^\s*function" regexfunc='\s*[&quot;\w_]+' regexend="" bodybegin="" bodyend="" sep="" />
</Group>
```

(this example works only for the first type of functions you have put as an example)

Comment: Thanks!  I've long since been using the SourceCookifier plugin (which is outstanding) instead of FunctionList, so I can't test this to verify - but I'll accept it for the effort ;)